# running gradle "war" doesn't include dependent intellij project

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I have an intellij project with two modules:

`web-services` (my API), `library-services` (business logic).

build.gradle of web-serivces:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply from: ext.gradleDir + '/common.gradle'
apply from: ext.gradleDir + '/integration_test.gradle'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
project.version = '1.0.' + getBuildNumber()


dependencies {
    compile project(':library-services')
    compile('com.waze.automation:common:1.0.80')

    compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19')
    compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19')
    compile group:  'org.codehaus.jackson', name:'jackson-jaxrs', version: '1.1.1'

    compile('com.google.guava:guava:18.0')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5')

}

war {
    from 'src/main' // include source files in war
}
```

I run this gradle command:

```
~/workspaceQa/MobileAutomationWebService/web-services ⮀
❯ ./gradlew war
```

but in the created war I don't see the classes of library-services

and my service throws `ClassNoFound` exception.

here is part of my log. how can i fix this?

```
12:10:28.081 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Tasks to be executed: [task ':library-services:compileJava', task ':library-services:processResources', task ':library-services:verifyDependencies', task ':library-services:classes', task ':library-services:setProjectVersion', task ':library-services:jar', task ':web-services:compileJava', task ':web-services:processResources', task ':web-services:verifyDependencies', task ':web-services:classes', task ':web-services:war']
```

Comment: I think you need runtime dependency. It extends compile dependency. It should be:  runtime project(':library-services'). According: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html (47.6)

Comment: why? it's should be dependent in compile time. no?

Comment: I think runtime extends compile and it seems that you need those classes in runtime, not only in compile time. With runtime your dependent project should be included in your lib folder and those classes will be ready for your web-services project

Comment: it doesn't work. the project doesn't even run. module a missing classes from module b

Comment: If it can help you. I have created 1 project with one submodule. To be able to see it under libs it was needed to do: compile project('submodule')
    runtime project('submodule'). It seems that you will need to maintain your compile project adding one more line with runtime project

Comment: After I removed this line the problem was solved:

    #org.gradle.parallel=true

Answer (score 0):

Here is a weird gradle IntelliJ behavior I noticed. Might be just gradle, but I don't usually use gradle outside of IntelliJ. So, I can't say for sure.
In any case, when the source set module I am including has a name alphabetically after the name of the module I am including it in. The WAR is missing the classes from the included module. Not sure what is causing it, but I put an underscore at the beginning of the included module and it includes the classes.
Not an ideal solution, but works for me because I have a single core source set that I include in my API modules. It took a while before it became a problem for me because my core module is called api-core. Everything worked fine until I added an "activities" API module.
I am always reluctant to post this kind of work-around solution without knowing exactly what the mechanism is. I hope it is helpful, and if anyone knows what is the root cause and has a better solution. I am all ears. :)

Answer (score -1):

After I removed this line the problem was solved:

gradle.properties file:

```
#org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution unless nothing else comes up since it could significantly increase the compile time on a large project.